# strike a balance between A and B

Tags: word-order, ambiguity

I am wondering if the following sentences are right or formal in written.

1. We have to strike a balance between A and B.
2. A balance between A and B has to be struck.
3. A balance has to be struck between A and B.

If they all are formal in writen, which one is the best between 2 and 3?

Comment: The first example is better than the latter two.  Options two and three look "forced" and unnatural where Option one is the most commonly used.

Comment: It's 'struck' rather than 'striked', and there can only be 'better' between two things - 'best' needs three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are  idiomatic expressions but the first one sounds more common in usage.  Note that in the second and the third sentences you should use "struck""

***[Strike a balance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/strike-a-balance)***: 
​

> - If you strike a balance between two things, you accept parts of both things in order to satisfy some of the demands of both sides in an argument, rather than all the demands of just one side:
>
>   - It's a question of striking the right balance between quality and productivity.

Cambridge Dictionary